# Git remote and GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY

Tags: git

I have repository with SSH verification, but also I have second repository with clone method (GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone git-address).

How I can add second repository (git remote add ...)?

Comment: How about: `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git remote add`

Comment: Thanks you, that is ok tip.

I must before every run set `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`, example: `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git fetch`, after is all ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a second remote with SSL verification off:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git remote add
```

Note that whenever you work with that remote, for example fetch, pull, and so on, you will need to prefix the commands with `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`.

When that becomes annoying, you can disable SSL verification permanently for the working tree, by running:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

Note however that this will disable SSL verification for all remotes in the working tree. This is not a recommended practice, as it undermines the security of the other remotes.