# I would like to make deployment to Azure web app from a private git repository

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I pull the source code from a private git repository into my computer and then I push it with local git repository into the web app on Azure cloud. I want to pull the source code directly into the Azure cloud without any middle copy process. I added Azure web app outbound IP addresses into the white list of my private repository and then I saved its url as an external deployment option of Azure web app.

But I can't run the following comments with Kudu console it gives permission error:

```
git config --global user.name "<Name Surname>"
git config --global user.email <email>
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1; git clone https://<url_of_private_git_repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, you are missing remote authentication. 
Just look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs 
Also a thread containing your error: [Git remote and GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021261/git-remote-and-git-ssl-no-verify)